# Is it possible to get the original host and port when enabling proxying on the JVM?

Tags: java, sockets, tcp

I'm interested in recording the TCP communication of a Java program to enable later replay - similar to what VCR frameworks like [Betamax](http://freeside.co/betamax/) do. The challenge is to create a proxy for recording the TCP traffic without altering the original Java program.

My initial idea: Say I have an arbitrary Java program that opens TCP connections to different services (e.g. a database) and I set the `socksProxyHost` property of the JVM to connect to localhost where I run a program with the following code:

```
ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(1080);
Socket socket             = serverSocket.accept();
```

Is there any way I can read the original host and port setting that the Java program was trying to reach (before applying the `socksProxyHost` and `socksProxyPort` option)? If so then I could open a new socket with the original host and port and forward/record the data.

Or is there another way to record/replay the TCP communication between the (blackbox) Java program (i.e. assume the source code is not available) and the services the program uses?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there any way I can read the original host and port setting that the Java program was trying to reach (before applying the socksProxyHost and socksProxyPort option)?

The host and port that the SOCKs client is trying to reach are part of the client->server message.  It is all explained in the [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOCKS).

Indeed, there are a few existing Java libraries supporting the SOCKs protocol.

Comment: What existing Java libraries support the SOCKs protocol? Any API that I could use for proxy'ing?

Comment: @Nicholas - you can use Google as well as I can my friend :-)

Comment: And I have - without finding any obvious, good candidates. I asked because you might know :-)

Comment: 1) That is not what you asked.  2) I don't have any recommendations anyway. 3) You have not specified your criteria for "good".